# Dropwizard configuration with list of strings in environment variable with default fallback?

Tags: dropwizard

Dropwizard takes `.yml` configurations which of course allow lists. It also has the `${FOO:-bar}` syntax which allows reading environment variables with default fallback.

Is there a way to read lists of strings from an env variable and parse automatically with Dropwizard or do I have to do it manually? What is the syntax to have a default fallback list if this exists? I could not find this in their documentation.

Comment: https://www.dropwizard.io/en/latest/manual/configuration.html#server-push Note the field `refererHosts` in the example. It's a list of values. Maybe it's possible to use this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thic can be achived by using a json format in the default parameter:

```
supported_locales: ${SUPPORTED_LOCALES:-[en,da_DK,pt_BR,es]}
```

This will make a config parameter called supported_locales which takes a SUPPORTED_LOCALES env variable (json array of strings format), and defaults to the array provided after the `-` character in this case `[en,da_DK,pt_BR,es]`